# Getting Error in Selenium C# With NSEINdia

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am facing problem in Selenium c#. I have looked in c# and found code in Phython. But Not able to find working in C#. Can you please guide me what's wrong in the code.

```
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.AddArguments("--start-maximized");
            List<string> ls = new List<string>();
            ls.Add("enable-automation");
            options.AddExcludedArguments(ls);
            options.AddAdditionalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
            options.AddAdditionalOption("chrome.page.customHeaders.referrer", "https://www.nseindia.com");

            using (var driver = new ChromeDriver(options))
            {
                driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.nseindia.com/api/ipo-bid-details?symbol=DREAMFOLKS&series=EQ");
            }
```

I am getting error "Resource not found". The URL is working if I navigate directly.

Comment: For me, it also shows "Resource not found". 

Maybe the website returns the content if some conditions are matched. Like Geo of ip belongs to the certain country and the browser is not automated. 

Also, take a look into `window.navigator` properties, maybe that allows the website to detect an automation (which may be not allowed)

Comment: Why do you feel `chrome.page.customHeaders.referrer` can enable you to access the url `https://www.nseindia.com/api/ipo-bid-details?symbol=DREAMFOLKS&series=EQ`? Documentation?

Comment: @undetectedSelenium, because of the same site I just thought to tried for it.

Comment: any suggestion guys ? I am still not able to work it. I did the changes but nothing work.